# Dropping files onto the app's dock icon works except for proxy icons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, dock, uti

I want to be able to accept drops on my app's dock icon from files, URLs, and text.  Since files (public.file-url) are a subtype of URL (public.url), I added just two Services entries to my Info.plist:

```
Services
  Item 0 (processURL)
    Instance method Name = processURL
    Send Types
      Item 0 = public.url
    Menu
      Menu item title = Process URL
  Item 1 (processString)
    Instance method Name = processString
    Send Types
      Item 0 = public.plain-text
    Menu
      Menu item title = Process Text
```

Then I made my `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` call `[NSApp setServicesProvider: self]`, and wrote a couple methods (`-processString:userData:error` and `-processURL:userData:error`) there in my application delegate.  The app icon now accepts drops of all three types.  In the `-processURL:...` method, it's easy to check if it's a local file or not, so that handles both of those cases.

One case still eludes me, though.  When I try dragging a window's *proxy icon* to the app, it highlights the icon as if it can accept the drop, but then my method isn't called.

I tried dropping proxy icons from Xcode, Terminal, Preview, and some third-party apps: none would call my services method.  But strangely, a proxy icon dropped from the Finder worked fine.

I tried changing `public.url` to `public.item` (the base type of the physical hierarchy), but my method is still not called for non-Finder proxy icons.

When the Finder successfully drops a proxy icon on my app, the pboard `-types` it provides are:

- "public.file-url",
- "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x6675726C",
- "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4grf0gn5xbrzw1gydcr7u1e3cytf2gn",
- NSFilenamesPboardType,
- "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
- "Apple URL pasteboard type"

I tried using each of these directly as the "Send Types".  "public.file-url" and "NSFilenamesPboardType" highlight the icon as if it'll accept the drop, but don't.  The others, unsurprisingly, don't even highlight the dock icon.

I can't find any reference to proxy icons having a different UTI than normal files.  Do they?  That would be weird.

I know this must be possible, because I can drag proxy icons from any window onto a Terminal window.  What am I missing?

UPDATE: From an NSView, if I `-registerForDraggedTypes` including "public.url", I do get drops of proxy icons from all apps, with exactly the same `-types` list as from the Finder, listed above.  So it's clearly something special to receiving drops via the dock icon.  This should still be possible somehow: you can drag a proxy icon from a (non-Finder) window (e.g., an .xcworkspace from Xcode) onto the Terminal dock window, and it catches that just fine.

Comment: What are proxy icons?

Comment: El Tomato: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/art/wn_standardwindowparts_2x.png

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 for your app delegate

```
func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile: String) -> Bool {
    Swift.print("sender \(sender) file \(openFile)")
    return true
}

func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles: [String]) {
    Swift.print("sender \(sender) list \(openFiles)")
    // Create a FileManager instance
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    for path in openFiles {

        do {
            let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
            for file in files {
                _ = self.application(sender, openFile: file)// void return
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Yoink \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement dragging files to your dock icon using [application:openFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenFile%3a) in your NSApplicationDelegate, then dragging proxy icons should work too. The trick to accepting all files is adding a Document Type with extensions of '*'.